# $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ is a cyclic $A$-module $\iff \rm{Ann}(M_1)+\rm{Ann}(M_2)=A$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with an identity element $1$.
An element $x$ in an $A$-module $M$ is called cyclic if $Ax=M$.
An $A$-module which has a cyclic element is called cyclic $A$-module.

Let $M_{1},M_{2}$ be cyclic $A$-modules and 
$I_{1},I_{2}$ annihilators of $M_{1},M_{2}$ respectively:
$$
I_{k}=\{ a \in A \mid ax=0\ (\forall x \in M_{k}) \}
\ \ \ (k=1,2).
$$
Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition for 
the direct sum $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ to be a cyclic $A$-module
is that $I_{1}+I_{2}=A$.

**My attempt:**

"$\Longrightarrow$": We know that
$$M_{1} \oplus M_{2} \simeq M_1\times M_2 \simeq A/I_1 \times A/I_2 \simeq A/(I_1 \cap I_2).$$
Since $A/(I_1 \cap I_2)$ is a cyclic $A$-module with a cyclic element $1+I_1 \cap I_2$, we must
have $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ is cyclic. But it seems that condition 
$I_{1}+I_{2}=A$ is not necessary?

"$\Longleftarrow$": Assume that $M_{1} \oplus M_{2}$ is cyclic then 
$$M_{1} \oplus M_{2} \simeq A/\rm{Ann}(M_1 + M_2) \simeq A/(I_1 \cap I_2).$$
I know that if $M_{1} \oplus M_{2} \simeq A/I_1I_2$ then $I_1 \cap I_2 =I_1I_2$ forcing
$I_{1}+I_{2}=A$. But how can I prove that?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The last isomorphism you wrote requires precisely that $I_1 + I_2 = A$ (see for example how it fails if $I_1 = I_2$).

Comment: Which isomorphism did you mean? $A/\rm{Ann}(M_1 + M_2) \simeq A/(I_1 \cap I_2)$? I think isn't well-known that $\rm{Ann}(M_1 + M_2)=\rm{Ann}(M_1)\cap \rm{Ann}(M_2)$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a poor description of which one I meant. I mean $A/I_1\times A/I_2 \cong A/(I_1\cap I_2)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $I+J \neq A$. Let $\mathfrak m$ be maximal ideal containing $I+J$.

We get a surjection $A/I \oplus A/J \twoheadrightarrow A/\mathfrak m \oplus A/\mathfrak m$.

If $A/I \oplus A/J$ was cyclic, we can compose this surjection with $A \twoheadrightarrow A/I \oplus A/J$ to get a surjection

$$A \twoheadrightarrow A/\mathfrak m \oplus A/\mathfrak m$$

After tensoring with $A/\mathfrak m =: k$, we get a surjection

$$k \to k^2,$$

which is absurd.

This shows: If $I+J \neq A$, $A/I \oplus A/J$ is not cyclic. Precisely, what you wanted.

Comment: It isn't quite clear to me that $k \to k^2$ cannot be a surjection? Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: basic linear algebra tells you that there is no surjective linear map $k \to k^2$.